# larave-livewire request(post and get) not working on staging server but return view liverwire with data is working

Tags: laravel-livewire

larave-livewire request(post and get) not working on staging server but return view liverwire with data is working.

below is the error
[image: Error image1]
[image: Error image2]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. updated apche config on SSL